# data attribute only working in toggle device mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I have the following HTML:

```
<div class = "someClass"  val = "{{$whatever->id}}" data-foo = "bar">
```

Well, I want to use data-foo in a condition, but first I'm printing out using console.log to test and see if it works.

So I have: 

`console.log($(this).attr("data-foo"));`

And it only gives me the answer 'foo' when I'm in chrome's toggle device mode. Why is that happening? I need to use it in a web page.

Does the data attribute only works for mobile devices?

Thanks!

Comment: It might also depend on how and where you put your console.log. Does it output anything and/or is executed at all? Maybe you can execute it in $(document).ready(...) to make sure the page was fully loaded before you use jquery to find the element and print the attribute to your log. It's hard to say without having more information.

Comment: @Luzzzzel

Look at what I'm doing:
`if ((border == "3px solid rgb(0, 0, 255)")) {

 console.log($(this).attr("data-foo"));

 $(this).css("border", "3px solid green");

}`
The interesting thing here is that without changing anything on the code, it prints "data-foo" on the console when I'm in toggle device mode, but it doesn't print anything when I'm using normally on the browser.
PS: this if is inside a javascript method, which is called when I click in a div. 
Hope it was useful

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at your "if" and check if the body there is executed at all? Maybe your CSS was overridden by something in the browser so the condition does not match. I mean if the color of your border changes the condition should match ...

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
console.log($('.someClass').data('foo'));
```

Comment: I also used it, but has the same effect. Only working when I'm in toggle device mode,

Comment: True, this makes the selector more specific, but only if there's only one div of that class. Though it will not overcome the problem if the page is not completely loaded yet, when the javascript/jquery is executed.

Comment: I agree with @Fuzzzzel, you should check if the code inside the **if** is executed or not, either you can set up a break point or use an **else** after the **if**. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to add comment directly under your post.